# What is a Taggy Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Taggy Word™**.
Use the following examples to find the rule.

| Taggy Words™ | Not Taggy Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ANIMAL | CREATURE |
| POET | SINGER |
| CROSS | LASER |
| LIAR | HONEST |
| NUMB | SHRILL |
| KNOW | REALIZE |
| LOG | TREE |
| FORM | LOOK |
| MATH | DIVIDE |
| ALTER | CHANGING |
| MYSTERY* | STRANGE |

*** This is a Very Taggy Word™**

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Taggy Words™,Not Taggy Words™
ANIMAL,CREATURE
POET,SINGER
CROSS,LASER
LIAR,HONEST
NUMB,SHRILL
KNOW,REALIZE
LOG,TREE
FORM,LOOK
MATH,DIVIDE
ALTER,CHANGING
MYSTERY*,STRANGE
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Taggy Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Taggy Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**
**Why are they called Taggy Words™ and Very Taggy Words™?**

Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a Taggy Word satisfies the property that

> It appears as a substring in one of the question tags on Puzzling Stack Exchange.

And a Very Taggy Word

> is a question tag on Puzzling Stack Exchange.

Examples

> animal appears in [animals](/questions/tagged/animals)
>  poet appears in [poetry](/questions/tagged/poetry)
>  cross appears in [crosswords](/questions/tagged/crosswords)
>  liar appears in [liars](/questions/tagged/liars)
>  numb appears in [number-sequence](/questions/tagged/number-sequence)
>  know appears in [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge)
>  log appears in [logic-grid](/questions/tagged/logic-grid)
>  [mystery](/questions/tagged/mystery) is a tag itself

Comment: How would you justify animal?

Comment: Good job, and solved it quick! Will accept it when I can :)

Comment: @Quark-epoch There is a tag named `animals`

Comment: @Supersonic Is there? I didn't know.

Comment: @Quark-epoch I've never seen it before either, I went to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags to search the tags :)